# Get year from python datetimefield object

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print SDstDate
```

gives below output:

```
<peewee.DateTimeField object at 0x7fd9dc8b0950>
```

and

```
print SDstDate.year
```

gives below output:

```
<peewee.Func object at 0x7f3737b0ef10>
```

Please help how can i extract the extract year from SDstDate.
SDstDate is a dattetimefield object which i have fetched from mysql database through peewee.

Comment: @Ajay i get error:  TypeError: 'Func' object is not callable  when use   print SDstDate.year()

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: DateTimeField objects are used to query tables. E.g. `foo.select().where(foo.SDstDate.year == 2015)`

Comment: @Ogen - I think you have understood my question well. CAn you please tell me how can i print that year instead of comparing.

Comment: @AfrozAlam That's the thing. This datetimefield object does not correspond to an entry. You have to use it to obtain desired entries in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's say you have a model with a DateTimeField indicating when a blog entry is published:

```
class Blog(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField()
```

To retrieve the year from a list of posts, simply do:

```
for post in Blog.select():
    print post.timestamp.year
```

Because the value in the `timestamp` field is a Python `datetime`, you can access properties on it like `year`, `month`, etc.

On the other hand, to *query* for blog entries published in a given year, you can write:

```
posts_this_year = Blog.select().where(Blog.timestamp.year == 2015)
for post in posts_this_year:
    # ... do whatever ...
```